# Where is .dxf file of this frame(Prusa i3)?

Tags: prusa-i3

I am looking for this fram, but in github there is no download option for it!
So I did copy the code and paste it, but in result when I measure the big frame's edges it shows bigger 9100mm !! but I think the frame's maximum edge size should be under 45cm?

May someone put's the .dxf file instead of referencing to github page?

[image]

Comment: There are many variations of the i3, you need to include more information like the github you are trying to get this from.

Comment: @tjb1: https://github.com/josefprusa/Prusa3/blob/master/old_single_plate/src/frame/6mm/Prusa3ALU-FREZOVANY-v4.dxf-old

Comment: @user145959, press the "Raw" button and save page as dxf. But your description of measurements and photo of your printer from previous question suggests it's not the right part. It's for original Prusa i3, while you own a variation of it.

Comment: @ZuOverture: you can write it as an answer!